# Do firefox or chrome provide API for extensions to open SSL session?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, ssl

Do firefox or chrome provide API for extensions to open SSL session?
I only find APIs of both firefox and chrome to send normal http request. But I need the informaion I send by my extension encrypted.

Comment: Are you talking about [XHR](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html)? You just use an `https://` protocol and the browsers will automatically make the request over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

For firefox add-ons, the [request module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/request.html) allows you to make web requests.  It doesn't say so explicitly, but it will handle https reqeusts as well.